# Odd .NET application behavior when installed in Program Files

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, exception, visual-studio-2015

I'm seeing some odd behavior with a .NET application which I am struggling to understand. I have an application written in C#, targeting .NET 4.5.2 which I am trying to deploy for testing purposes. The application has been working fine when running under Visual Studio (2015) and also for a while when deployed to C:\Program Files (x86). However, today I tried to run the application again and it immediately throws a dreaded System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (The operation completed successfully).

The application still runs fine under the Visual Studio debugger, and also runs fine if I run it manually from the Visual Studio release directory. Interestingly, the application also runs fine if I either:

- Rename the executable in the program files directory (e.g. from x.exe to y.exe)
- Rename the directory in which it is located inside program files

The only things I can think of so far are:

- Something else on my machine is causing a problem with it (anti virus perhaps?). Though I can't find anything in the logs to support this.
- Windows is some how caching an old version of the executable and using this? I'm not sure whether this actually happens or not though, it's just a thought.

I took a look through the event viewer and see errors relating to this, but the log entries don't provide any extra information over what is given in the exception.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
I tried attaching the VS debugger to the process but it doesn't give me any extra information. However, I just changed the start action under the project debug settings to run the executable located in program files and it throws a different exception:"Managed Debugging Assistant 'FatalExecutionEngineError' has detected a problem in 'C:\Program Files (x86)..."

Additional information: The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x010cf00c, on thread 0x1d00. The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.

If I continue past that exception, I get another immediately after:
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in Unknown Module."

Comment: Check the event viewer.. Sounds like a possible permissions issue. edit: I see you checked the event viewer... Try attaching the VS debugger to the application process..

Comment: @daveL: Thanks for the suggestion. I added some extra information in my edit above.

Comment: If you get FEEE then anything is possible.  It doesn't get detected immediately, usually only when the garbage collector runs.  Before that happens your program is running with a corrupted heap.  *Anything* can happen.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here turned out to be that somehow, the compatibility mode for the executable within the Program Files directory had been set to "Windows 95"! I have no idea how this ended up like this (I certainly didn't set it!) but either way, when compatibility mode is disabled, all works as expected (unsurprisingly)! Thanks to everyone who commented.